# PyQt doesn't know it's in fullscreen

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm creating a small GUI with the help auf Qt Designer. I then translated the it to python code and continued to work from there.

I want the window to start in window mode with the size (1852,1136). However even though I never set the window to start at fullscreen it does it anyway.

First, I tried changing the window state to Qt.WindowNoState. This didn't change anything. I checked Qt.WindowMinimized state to check if it's a code problem but it did work.

Afterwards I tried the resize method:

```
 w.resize(1852, 1136)
```

However this didn't change anything either.
Now here comes the weird part:
When I try to resize it to e.g. (1200, 1136) it does work.
I then tried to find the sweet spot:
When setting the size to (1536, 1136) the resizing works, window is smaller.
When setting the size to (1537, 1136) the window is in fullscreen.

Somehow the GUI doesn't know that it's in fullscreen:

```
# Printing size without change
print(w.size())
>> PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(1852, 1136)

# Check if fullscreen
print(w.isFullScreen())
>> False

# Go Fullscreen
w.showFullScreen()
# Printing size after fullscreen
print(w.size())
>> PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(1852, 1136)

# Check if fullscreen
print(w.isFullScreen())
>> True

# Go window mode / normal mode
w.showNormal()
# printing size after normal mode
print(w.size())
>> PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(1852, 1136)

# Check if Fullscreen
print(w.isFullScreen())
>> False

# Resize to 1537
w.resize(1537, 1136)
# print size after 1537
print(w.size())
>> PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(1537, 1136)

# Resize to 1536
w.resize(1536, 1136)
# printing size after 1536
print(w.size())
>> PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(1536, 1136)
```

My questions are:

- Why does it start in full screen even though it's not in fullscreen mode?
- How can I fix it?

I'm running the application in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I'm using a 4K screen to display the application (1852, 1136) fits easily. I can also make the window smaller by pressing the standard "window mode" button on the top right and it's in the right size afterwards.

Thank you in advance!

Regarding @musicamante comment:

Minimal example:
I can just create an empty GUI and it still has the same behavior:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(1852, 1136)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1852, 22))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar) 
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))







app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Ui_MainWindow()
w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ex.setupUi(w)
w.show()

# Fullscreen at (1852, 1136)
print(f"App is in fullscreen even though it's set at {w.size()} and Fullscreen check returns: {w.isFullScreen()}")

# Resize to (1536, 1136)
w.resize(1536, 1136)
print(f"App is not in Fullscreen anymore after resize: {w.size()}")

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

> ```
> App is in fullscreen even though it's set at PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(1852, 1136) and Fullscreen check returns: False
> ```

> ```
> App is not in Fullscreen anymore after resize: PyQt5.QtCore.QSize(1536, 1136)
> ```

Comment: What window manager are you using? Are you using Wayland? Did you check the system preferences if there's some related option you may have switched by mistake? Are those lines from the interactive shell or from your code? In the second case, please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante
I'm using the x-window-manager.

I added an example in the original post.
Thank you!

Comment: You're using the wrong function. QWidget.resize() doesn't set the window to fullscreen mode. It simply changes the screen size to something bigger or smaller depending on the parameters. If you want to create a fullscreen window, use QWidget.showFullscreen. That will make it work for any kind of monitor (even one that has a different screen size than yours).

Comment: Your concept of "full screen" is unclear. Do you mean "maximized"? Can you please provide accurate screenshots of your screen? Also, as the [docs explain](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/application-windows.html#x11-peculiarities), on X11 the actual window sizes may not be instantly applied due to the way window managers implement window geometries (and when). Long story short, getting the current window size (using `size()`, `width()`, `height()`, `geometry()` or `frameGeometry()`) may not be consistent at the specific moment those functions are called, especially if the window is still being *mapped*.